# How to convert neo4j return types to python types

Tags: python, neo4j, type-conversion, py2neo

I am using py2neo and I would like to extract the information from query returns so that I can do stuff with it in python. For example, I have a DB containing three "Person" nodes:

`for num in graph.cypher.execute("MATCH (p:Person) RETURN count(*)"):
     print num`

outputs:

`>> count(*)`

`3`

Sorry for shitty formatting, it looks essentially the same as a mysql output. However, I would like to use the number 3 for computations, but it has type `py2neo.cypher.core.Record`. How can I convert this to a python int so that I can use it? In a more general sense, how should I go about processing cypher queries so that the data I get back can be used in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`graph.cypher.execute()` returns a `RecordList` containing multiple `Records`. Each `Record` corresponds to a single line of the result of your Cypher query.

Your `RETURN count(*)` query returns only one line, so the `for num in ...` loop will only touch one `Record` in your `RecordList`.

To get data from the columns of a record, you can use indices or column names:

```
for num in ... :
    your_count = num[0] # gets the first column
```

This should be an `int`, but you can now convert it to whatever you need with `float()` or `int()`.

---

Your query returns only one line with one column. You can shorten it to:

```
your_count = graph.cypher.execute("MATCH (p:Person) RETURN count(*)")[0][0]
```

The first `[0]` gets the first `Record` of your resulting `RecordList` and the second `[0]` gets the first column of the `Record`.

Have a look at: http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html#records

Answer (score 0):

can you int(), float() str() on the `__str__()` method that looks to be outputting the value you want in your example?

Comment: int() directly doesn't work because it doesn't take Record as input. Using str() outputs a string containing `count(*) --------------` and other visual debris included when outputting the number 3

Comment: what do you get with num[0]