# Output py2neo recordlist to text file

Tags: python, neo4j, type-conversion, py2neo

I am trying to use python (v3.4) to act as a 'sandwich' between Neo4j and a text output file. This code gives me a py2neo [RecordList](http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html#py2neo.cypher.RecordList):

```
from py2neo import Graph
from py2neo.packages.httpstream import http
http.socket_timeout = 9999
graph = Graph('http://localhost:7474/db/data/')
sCypher = 'MATCH (a) RETURN count(a)'
results = graph.cypher.execute(sCypher)
```

I also have some really simple text file interaction:

```
f = open('Output.txt','a') #open for append access
f.write ('\n Hello world')
f.close
```

What I really want to do is `f.write (str(results))` but it really didn't like that at all. Can someone help me to convert my RecordList into a string please? I'm assuming I'll need to loop through the columns to get each column name, then loop through each record and write it individually, but I don't know how to go about this. Where I'm eventually planning to go with this is to change the Cypher every time.

Closest related question I could find is this one: [How to convert Neo4j return types to python types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29682897/how-to-convert-neo4j-return-types-to-python-types/29715932). I'm sure there's someone out there who'll read this and say that using the REST API directly is a much better way of spitting out text, but I'm not quite at that level...

Thanks in advance, 
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can iterate a `RecordList` and print the columns of the individual `Records` to a file (e.g. comma separated). If the properties you return are lists you would need some more formatting to get strings for your output file.

```
# use with to open files, this makes sure that it's properly closed after an exception
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    # iterate over individual Records in RecordList
    for record in results:
        # concatenate all columns of the Record into a string, comma separated
        # list comprehension with str() to handle int and other types
        output_string = ','.join([str(x) for x in record])
        # actually write to file
        print(output_string, file=f)
```

The format of the output file depends on what you want to do with it of course.

Comment: Martin, sorry for the slow reply. This worked a treat. I didn't think it was working at first as I got an error message but apparently that was caused by a non-unicode charactor in my source data. Next I need to figure out how to format the data to look as pretty as the `RecordList` wrapper within the python shell, but this is really useful. Thanks for your help.